# Translate English to Pig Latin

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, pig-latin

This is a program for converting English to the pseudo-language Pig Latin. Not the strictest form of Pig Latin but it most likely will accurately output an argument in Pig Latin. I got the idea from a list of ideas on [Github](https://github.com/karan/Projects). Is there any way I can improve it concisely?

```
def pig_latin(message):
    consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y',
                  'z']
    new_message = ''

    for word in message.split():
        ay = ['a', 'y']
        listed_word = list(word)
        word_copy = word
        moved_consonants = ''

        for letter in listed_word.copy():
            if letter.lower() == 'y':
                if letter in word_copy[0]:
                    moved_consonants += letter
                    listed_word.remove(letter)
                else:
                    break
            elif letter.lower() in consonants:
                moved_consonants += letter
                listed_word.remove(letter)
            else:
                break

        listed_word.append('-' + moved_consonants + ''.join(ay))
        new_message += ''.join(listed_word) + ' '

    return new_message


print(pig_latin('Can you read pig latin?'))
```

Comment: To the close voter (/ presumably downvoter), they said they got the *idea* from a github list, not the implementation. I don't see an authorship issue here.

Answer (score 18):

First, at the top you list all the consonants out. There are two things that can be improved here:

- Since you only use it to check whether or not something is a consonant, it should be a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). It's much more efficient to to a membership lookup on a set than it is to do one on a list. Just replace the `[]` with `{}`.

  ```
  consonants = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
  ```
- Second, there's a slightly less painful way to generate those letters. Python's `string` module contains a `ascii_lowercase` built-in that holds `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. You can use that along with a set of vowels to limit what letters need to be hard-coded:

  ```
  import string as s

  vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
  consonants = set(s.ascii_lowercase) - vowels  # Consonants are the set of letters, minus the vowels
  ```

  I personally prefer this way.

You could also just change your algorithm to use `vowels` directly.

---

Just to clear something up,

```
word_copy = word
```

does *not* create a copy of `word`. This just creates a second name for the `word` string. For Strings this doesn't matter because Strings are immutable, but with a mutable object, this will bite you:

```
my_list = []
list_copy = my_list  # Does not actually create a copy!
my_list.append(1)
print(my_list, list_copy)  # prints [1] [1]
```

Notice how *both* lists were added to. This happens because there's actually only one list. Both names are referring to the same list.

For the sake of clarity, I'd rename it to say what it's *purpose* is. Offhand though, I can't see the need for `word_copy` at all! It would make sense if it was being used as an accumulator for a loop or something, but the only time its ever used is at `word_copy[0]`, and since you never reassign `word`, you could just do `word[0]`. I'd simply get rid of `word_copy`.

Along the same lines, I'd reconsider `ay`. The name you've given it is exactly as descriptive as the string it contains, and is only ever used in one place. At the very least, I'd rename it to something meaningful:

```
pig_latin_suffix = ['a', 'y']
```

I'll also note that there's no reason to use a list of Strings here instead of a multi-character String. They behave the same in this case:

```
" ".join(['a', 'y'])
'a y'

" ".join("ay")
'a y'
```

Strings are iterable just like lists are.

---

I think `pig_latin` is too big. It's doing two main jobs: breaking the message into words, and processing the words. I would make the processing step its own function:

```
def process_word(word):
    ay = ['a', 'y']
    listed_word = list(word)
    word_copy = word
    moved_consonants = ''

    for letter in listed_word.copy():
        if letter.lower() == 'y':
            if letter in word_copy[0]:
                moved_consonants += letter
                listed_word.remove(letter)
            else:
                break
        elif letter.lower() in consonants:
            moved_consonants += letter
            listed_word.remove(letter)
        else:
            break

    listed_word.append('-' + moved_consonants + ''.join(ay))

    return ''.join(listed_word)

def pig_latin(message):
    new_message = ''

    for word in message.split():
        processed_word = process_word(word)

        new_message += processed_word + ' '

    return new_message
```

`process_word` could arguably be broken down further. This is already much better though. The immediate benefit is now you can test individual words, and not have to worry about how the rest of the code will react:

```
print(process_word("Can"))  # Prints 'an-Cay'
```

Comment: `print(process_word("Can?"))` "an?-Cay" probably isn't what OP wanted.

Comment: @Griffin That's what their's prints. I was just rolling with it.

Comment: for what its worth if you do need to create a genuine copy the way to do that would be:  `from copy import deepcopy; word_copy = deepcopy(word)`. That way you're actually creating a copy and not just a reference to the original

Comment: @TheSaint321 I can't think of a circumstance where you would ever need to copy a String though. I wouldn't be surprised if `deepcopy` just immediately returns Strings passed to it.

Comment: yup thought about it for another second you're right. There's no point in deep copying a string. Its still a pretty useful tool nevertheless for more complicated objects

Comment: Is there a reason for implementing the loop explicitly in `pig_latin` instead of a simple `return ' '.join(process_word(word) for word in message.split())`?

Comment: @PiCTo Honestly, I was (and still am) suffering from the stomach flu. I only had the will to point out what was immediately obvious to me. You could post an answer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry to read that; I hope I did not offend you. I was asking a genuine question as I believed that might be an improvement. I don't have the will to write a throughout answer to this question but, if you agree that the one-liner I propose is better (and that there are no reason not to use it), I will gladly edit your answer.

Comment: @PiCTo No worries, it's potentially a legitimate recommendation. I'll look at it when staring at screens stops making me nauseous.

Answer (score 12):

As this is a simple text transformation, the regular-expression module `re` is your friend.

Processing letters one at a time is h-a-r-d.  It would be simpler to process things one word at a time, as suggested by @Carcigenicate.

The [`re.sub(pattern, repl, text, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.sub) function is interesting in that it allows you to specify a string **or a function** for the replacement.  As a first approximation:

```
import re

def pig_latin(text):

    def transform(match):
        first, rest = match.group(1, 2)
        if first.lower() in "aeiou":
            return first + rest + 'way'
        else:
            return rest + first + 'ay'

    return re.sub(r'(\w)(\w*)', transform, text)

print(pig_latin("Can you read pig latin?"))
```

> anCay ouyay eadray igpay atinlay?

Here, the regex is extracting entire words with two capturing groups.  The first group is simply the first letter `\w`, an the second group is the rest of the letters (if any) in the word `\w*`.  The `match` is passed to the `transform` function, from which groups #1 and #2 are extracted and assigned to `first` and `rest`.  If the `first` letter is a vowel, the replacement text is generated one way; if not it is generated a second way.  The returned value is used as the replacement in the `re.sub(...)` call.

The `transform` function can easily be modified to include the `-`, if desired, as well as additional special handling of `y`, if required.